# ReportViewers going crazy after adding new report

Tags: wpf, vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc

so after i add a couple of folders on my project and add a new .rdlc file when i try to rebuild my project i get this error on all my .rdlc files, even tho i havent touch them for months. The error is:

```
An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘-1073741819’
```

Cant find anything on the internet related to this 1073741819 error value. Does anyone know what does that means?

i'm using visual studio 2010 with vb.net and wpf.

Thanks

Comment: I could fix this problem by restarting my pc. Dunno what was wrong but it solve my problem..

Comment: Problem is back, after a few hours of work i cant rebuild my project again! Is there no one able to tell me what is wrong?